# Characters on ray class groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, characters

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field, $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers, $\mathfrak{m}$ an integral ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $J$ be the set of all fractional ideals, $P$ the set of principal fractional ideals, $P^+$ the set of principal fractional ideals $(\alpha)$ such that $\alpha$ is totally real, $J_\mathfrak{m}$ the group of fractional ideals that are coprime to $\mathfrak{m}$, and $P_\mathfrak{m}^+$ the set of principal fractional ideals $(\alpha)$ such that $\alpha \equiv 1 \mod{\mathfrak{m}}$ and $\alpha$ is totally real. Further, let $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m})^\times$ be the multiplicative group mod $\mathfrak{m}$. I am interested in finite-order characters on the ray class group mod $\mathfrak{m}$, defined as the quotient group
$$
\mathcal{I}_\mathfrak{m} := \frac{J_\mathfrak{m}}{P_\mathfrak{m}^+}.
$$
Specifically, my question is as follows:

**Is it true (or, under which circumstances is the following true) that any character $\xi$ on the ray class group $\mathcal{I}_\mathfrak{m}$ may be written as $\xi = \chi \psi$, where $\chi$ is a character on the multiplicative group $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m})^\times$ and $\psi$ is a character on the narrow ideal class group $J/P^+$? Here both characters $\chi$ and $\psi$ are being extended from ideal classes to ideals in the obvious way.**

The ray class group $\mathcal{I}_\mathfrak{m}$ is constructed using congruence information ($\alpha \equiv 1 \mod{\mathfrak{m}}$), embedding information ($\alpha$ is totally real), and ideal class information (quotient by principal ideals). The first of these is encoded by the characters $\chi$, and the second and third are encoded by characters $\psi$. As such, it seems that these two sets of characters together should totally describe the characters on $\mathcal{I}_\mathfrak{m}$, but perhaps I'm missing something. Any comments would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The question makes no sense as it stands, because $\chi$ and $\psi$ are characters on different groups (so it makes no sense to multiply them). Also, I think that the property "$\alpha$ is totally real" should be changed to "$\alpha$ is totally positive", meaning that $\alpha$ is positive in every real embedding $K\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}$. With all this said, there is a way to interpret the question so that it has a reasonable answer (close to what the OP expects). What I am saying below is standard material, see e.g. Theorem 21.8 in [these notes by Andrew Sutherland](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2017fa/LectureNotes21.pdf).

Let $K_\mathfrak{m}^\times$ be the multiplicative group of elements of $K^\times$ coprime to $\mathfrak{m}$, and let $P_\mathfrak{m}$ be the multiplicative group of fractional ideals generated by the elements of $K_\mathfrak{m}^\times$. Let $K_\mathfrak{m,+}^{\times}$ be multiplicative group of totally positive elements of $K^\times$ coprime to $\mathfrak{m}$. Then we have an exact sequence
$$1\to\mathcal{O}_K^\times/(\mathcal{O}_K^\times\cap K^\times_{\mathfrak{m},+})\to K^\times_{\mathfrak{m}}/K^\times_{\mathfrak{m},+}\to J_\mathfrak{m}/P_{\mathfrak{m}}^+\to J_\mathfrak{m}/P_{\mathfrak{m}}\to 1.$$
By weak approximation, $J_\mathfrak{m}/P_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is isomorphic to the class group $J/P$, while $K^\times_{\mathfrak{m}}/K^\times_{\mathfrak{m},+}$ is isomorphic to $G=\{\pm 1\}^r\times(\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m})^\times$, where $r$ is the number of real places of $K$. So there is a subgroup $H\leq G$ isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_K^\times/(\mathcal{O}_K^\times\cap K^\times_{\mathfrak{m},+})$ such that there is a short exact sequence
$$1\to G/H\to J_\mathfrak{m}/P_{\mathfrak{m}}^+\to J/P\to 1.$$
In other words, the character group $\widehat{J/P}$ embeds into the character group $\widehat{J_\mathfrak{m}/P_{\mathfrak{m}}^+}$, and the corresponding quotient group is isomorphic to $\widehat{G/H}$. Note that $\widehat{G/H}$ is isomorphic to the group of characters of $G$ that are trivial on $H$. In general, the above short exact sequence does not split, so $J_\mathfrak{m}/P_{\mathfrak{m}}^+$ is not isomorphic to $(G/H)\times(J/P)$ even though they have the same order.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! You're definitely right that my question doesn't make sense as posed. This (and several of my previous questions) are part of my quest to decipher clumsy language in several papers; unfortunately this is also leading to clumsy questions on my part.